# Flicker artifacts in texture with tessellation

Tags: opengl, glsl, rendering, shader

I encountered a problem when using tessellation.

Please refer to the link below

You may see some grey area after the rendering. If I rotate camera, they also changed (like a shinning effect.)

Could any one help me to figure out what is the reason? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

Vertex Shader:

```
in vec3 vertex_position;
in vec2 vertex_texcoord;

void main()
{
    v_pos = vec3(vertex_position);
    v_texcoord = vertex_texcoord;
}
```

TC shader:

```
layout(vertices = 3) out;
in vec3 v_pos[];
in vec2 v_texcoord[];

out vec3 tc_pos[];
out vec2 tc_texcoord[];
#define ID gl_InvocationID
#define TESS_LEVEL_INNER 3.0
#define TESS_LEVEL_OUTER 2.0

void main()
{
    tc_pos[ID] = v_pos[ID];
    tc_texcoord[ID] = v_texcoord[ID];

    if (ID == 0)
    {
        gl_TessLevelInner[0] = TESS_LEVEL_INNER;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = TESS_LEVEL_OUTER;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = TESS_LEVEL_OUTER;
        gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = TESS_LEVEL_OUTER;
    }
}
```

Te shader:

```
layout(triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;
in vec3 tc_pos[];
in vec2 tc_texcoord[];

out vec3 te_pos;
out vec2 te_texcoord;
void main()
{
    vec3 p0 = gl_TessCoord.x * tc_pos[0];
    vec3 p1 = gl_TessCoord.y * tc_pos[1];
    vec3 p2 = gl_TessCoord.z * tc_pos[2];

    vec2 t0 = gl_TessCoord.x * tc_texcoord[0];
    vec2 t1 = gl_TessCoord.y * tc_texcoord[1];
    vec2 t2 = gl_TessCoord.z * tc_texcoord[2];

    te_pos = p0 + p1 + p2;
    te_texcoord = t0 + t1 + t2;

    vec4 p_t = vec4(te_pos-cam_pos.xyz,1.0) * cam_ori;
    gl_Position = perspective_mat * p_t;
}
```

geometry shader:

```
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=3) out;

in vec3 te_pos[3];
in vec2 te_texcoord[3];

out vec2 g_texcoord;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    g_texcoord = te_texcoord[0];
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    g_texcoord  = te_texcoord[1];
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    g_texcoord  = te_texcoord[2];
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment:

```
in vec2 g_texcoord;
out vec4 frag_color;
void main() 
{
    frag_color = texture(tex_unit, g_texcoord);
}
```

[Rendering Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJAwF.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! After the first look at the picture I'd guess you've primitives which are too close to one another.  The geometry look quite plain - can maybe you just add or subtract a small epsilon? Or cull efficiently? But - just a quick guess for now; I'll look at your shaders later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! For easier visualization, i red circled some of those incorrect place. Actually I feel the geometry input is supposed to be: they are mostly walls and floors

Comment: Yes, those are those artifacts I meant. Could  you try and lift the (top layer fo  the?) floor just roughly 1/1000 unit up?

Comment: Hi. @decltype_auto Thanks for pointing this out! I tried to run same code on a teapot smooth data, Then the tessellation works perfect. Do you think there is any way to fix this data to make it work correctly?

Comment: Not sure yet; simply try to move the planes a little apart, e.g. with a world space scale uniform, e.g. a mat4x4 = diag(1.001, 1.001, 1.001, 1.) for the outer, or its inverse for the inner primitives